# Finding Expected Value Expressions in 2 Ways

Tags: probability, statistics

> You know that T$_1$, T$_2$, and T$_3$ and i.i.d. with T$_j$$^{\frac{1}{B}}$ ~ Expo(λ), where B and λ are known constants. Find expressions for E(T$_1$$^2$) as integrals in two different ways: one using the PDF of T$_1$, and the other based on the Expo(λ) PDF (no need to simplify).

So, I did the brute work of calculating the PDF as follows:

f$_y$(y) = λ*e*$^{{-λ}^{\frac{1}{B}}}$$\frac{y^{\frac{1-B}{B}}}{B}$, y≥0. Now, I just need to find the integrals. Is my logic correct in that you can solve the first step as follows:
$\int_0^∞$ $\frac{1}{B}$ f$_y$(y)? 
 I have no idea how to do the second one. Can anyone help me with these two parts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician  First one asked you to do the transformation and obtain the pdf of $T_1$, and then find the expectation. Second one ask you to directly use the given pdf to find the expectation, using the so called law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: So I did the pdf of T1, which I think is correct. Using expectation, though, what do I plug in for the first term? What is T1$^2$? And I'm still confused about how to do the second part.

Comment: Give you an example. To find $E[X^2]$, you can first compute the pdf of $X^2$, $f_{X^2}$, then $\displaystyle E[X^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} uf_{X^2}(u)du$. On the other hand, you may compute directly via the pdf of $X$, $f_X(x)$, $\displaystyle E[X^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u^2f_{X}(u)du$